# How do I create user registration for a AbstractUser?

Tags: django

Since Django recommends having a custom user model for a new project, I've extended the AbstractUser model without adding any additional fields, but how do I create a signup page for new users with my new user model?

My model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating customer model you have to build registration form.
you can check out this video he explained it well.
Also you can add additional fields
[AbstractBaseUser and UserCreationForm](https://youtu.be/oZUb372g6Do)